# ¿Cuando conviene utilizar var, let y const en ECMA Script 6?

Tags: ecmascript-2015

En ECMA Script 6 se pueden definir las variables de javascript con **let** y **const**, además de utilizar **var**. ¿Cual sería la recomendación para elegir  que tipo de definición de variables debería utilizarse?

Comment: asociación: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Para responder a la pregunta:

> ¿Cual sería la recomendación para elegir que tipo de definición de variables debería utilizarse?

Primero se debe conocer cada tipo de sentencia y aclarar su alcance dentro de la ejecución de javascript:

> La sentencia [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/let) declara una variable de alcance local, la cual, opcionalmente puede ser inicializada con algún valor.

Es decir, ejemplo:

```js
(function(){
  let foo = 'bar'; // Se crea y se le da un valor
  let bar = 'foo'; // Se crea y se le da un valor
  
  console.log('foo: ' + foo); 
  console.log('bar: ' + bar);
  
  foo = 'foo'; // Se le asigna un nuevo valor
  bar = 'bar'; // Se le asigna un nuevo valor
  
  console.log('foo: ' + foo);
  console.log('bar: ' + bar);
})()

console.log('foo: ' + foo); // foo is not defined
console.log('bar: ' + bar); // bar is not defined
```

En el ejemplo anterior se puede apreciar con claridad como las variables `foo` y `bar` solo pueden ser inicializadas, accedidas y cambiadas únicamente dentro del `closure` pero no pueden ser accedidas y/o cambiadas por fuera de este...

**NOTA:** en el ejemplo anterior si se reemplaza a [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/let) por [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/var) se obtendrán los mismos resultados, solo lo puse como ejemplo, un mejor ejemplo sería decir que una variable [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/let) definida en *`archivo_1.js`* no podría ser accedida en *`archivo_2.js`* mientras que una variable [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/var) en *`archivo_1.js`* si podría ser accedida y cambiada en *`archivo_2.js`*

Además hay que aclarar  que las variables de tipo [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/let) a diferencia de las variables de tipo [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/var) **NO PUEDEN**
 ser accedidas mediante el objeto global *`window`* y **tampoco pueden ser re declaradas** a diferencia de las variables tipo [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/var), ejemplo:

```js
var bar = 'foo';
let foo = 'bar';

console.log('bar: ' + bar);
console.log('window bar: ' + window.bar);
console.log('foo: ' + foo);
console.log('window foo: ' + window.foo); // undefined

var bar = 'new foo'; // bar puede ser RE DECLARADA
// let foo = 'new bar'; // foo NO PUEDE ser RE DECLARADA

console.log('bar: ' + bar);
console.log('window bar: ' + window.bar);
console.log('foo: ' + foo);
console.log('window foo: ' + window.foo); // undefined
```

> La sentencia [var](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/var) es una simple declaración de una variable, opcionalmente inicializada a un valor.

Es decir:

```js
var foo = 'bar';
console.log(foo);
console.log(window.foo);
foo = 'foo';
console.log(foo);
console.log(window.foo);

(function(){
  console.log('closure foo: ' + foo);
  console.log('closure window foo: ' + window.foo);
})()
```

> La sentencia [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/const) es una **constante** que se presenta en un ámbito de bloque como lo hacen las variables de tipo [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/var) pero que no puede ser cambiadas*(*[las propiedades de los objetos asignados a las constantes no están protegidas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Constants)*) ni redeclaradas

Al actuar como variables de tipo [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/var) se debe tener en cuenta que tampoco pueden ser accededidas a través del objeto global *`window`*, **tampoco pueden** ser re declaradas y/o re asignadas con un nuevo valor

```js
const KEY = '0123456780';
console.log(KEY);
console.log(window.KEY); // undefined
// KEY = '0876543210'; // KEY' has already been declared
// const KEY = '0876543210'; // KEY' has already been declared
console.log(KEY);
console.log(window.KEY); // undefined

const data = {
           id : 1, 
           name : "top secret"
           }
 console.log(data) 
 
 data.id = 9 //the reference does not change it
 data.name = "Nine";
 console.log(data)
```

Por último y como conclusión quedarían algunas recomendaciones como:

**1.** Usa variables de tipo [**`let`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/let) dentro de *funciones*, *ciclos* y demás *bloques de código* que su ejecución sea local, no dependa de otro código y donde dichas variables no tengan porque ser accedidas de manera global mediante el objeto *`window`*

**2.** Usa variables de tipo [**`var`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/var) donde dicha variable tenga que ser accedida en otros bloques de código y de manera global mediante el objeto *`window`*, es decir: `var jq = $;`

**3.** Usa ***CONSTANTES*** ([**`const`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/const)) para información como lo puede ser una *API KEY*, un *TOKEN*, un valor que SIEMPRE TENGA QUE SER EL MISMO, es decir: `const my_credit_card_number = 1234567890;`

**NOTA:** solo haz el ejemplo anterior si estás en `nodejs`, jaja

Comment: En el ejemplo del closure `var` y `let` tienen el mismo efecto.

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo tienes razón, estoy editando aún mi pregunta, de todas maneras quería poner un ejemplo y me pareció sencillo utilizar un closure para ello, gracias por la observación

Comment: De nada!! Eso de que no se puedan acceder mediante window si que me parece interesante. No lo sabía. Saludos!!

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo Añadí una breve nota a la descripción del ejemplo para que sea más claro todo

Comment: @Jorius las variables `let` no pueden ser redeclaradas como lo hace `var`

Comment: @JuankGlezz ¿Redeclarar y asignar un nuevo valor es lo mismo? *legit question*

Comment: @Jorius lo que me refiero es que no puedes poner `var variable = 0` y en la siguiente  linea  u otras más abajo poner `let variable = 1`,  aquí es donde me confundí un poco _como lo hace `var`_

Comment: @JuankGlezz He actualizado mi respuesta aclarando lo de el redeclaramiento

Answer (score 9):

La diferencia entre `let` y `var` más importante es el alcance (o scope).
var hará que estén definidas las variables dentro de la función más cercana.
let hará solo está definido en el bloque cerrado más cercano. A parte var declara las variables en la parte superior de la función más cercana sin importar donde la declaremos, lo que se conoce como hoisting ([+info](https://www.campusmvp.es/recursos/post/que-es-el-hoisting-en-javascript.aspx)).

`let` tampoco permite que creemos una variable con el mismo nombre, aunque si permite modificarla (al contrario que `const`). Digamos que `const` tiene el mismo efecto que `let` con la diferencia de que no podemos modificar el valor primitivo que almacene. Si que podríamos modificar las propiedades de un objeto con `const`.

```js
//console.log(letvariable); //--> esto da error
console.log(varvariable);  // undefined -> Esto no ya que var hace que estén visibles en su función más próxima 

let letvariable = '';
var varvariable = '';

// De igual forma
(function(){
  //console.log(x); // -> error
  console.log(y); // undefined
  let x = 'x';
  var y = 'y'
})()


for(let a = 0; a < 9; a++){
}
//console.log(a); // a no esta definida
for(var b = 0; b < 9; b++){
}

console.log(b);

{
  let c = 'hello';
  var d = 'hello';
}
//console.log(c) // error

console.log(d);

let xx = '';
//let xx = 'xx'; //-> error

var yy = '';
var yy = 'aaaa';

console.log(yy);

const zz = 'aa';
//zz = 'bb'; // error

const objeto = {};

objeto.a = 'aa';
console.log(objeto);
```

Teniendo en cuenta esto, el uso de una o de otra depende de la funcionalidad que quieras tener en tu programa.