# ¿Cual es la diferencia de usar LET en vez de VAR en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Como dice la pregunta, que es mas optimo y por que?:

```
let carro = "subaru";

var carro = "subaru";
```

Comment: Si declara una variable tipo **var** es global, mientras que la variable tipo **let** es de alcance local.

Comment: posible duplicado: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/56116/cuando-conviene-utilizar-var-let-y-const-en-ecma-script-6

Comment: Quien me coloco el -1?, yo puse en el buscador varias veces y no aparecio nada de pregunta? entonces no es mi culpa :( , Que intensidad,

Comment: yo no te puse el -1 pero, si buscas de esta forma es el primer resultado que te sale: https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=let+var

Comment: yo no se que le pasa al buscador yo pongo las cosas y arroja solo 1 resultado, luego cuando publico me caen a palos jaajajaj, gracias @aldanux

Answer (score 17, accepted):

let permite declarar variables limitando su alcance (scope) al bloque, declaración, o expresión donde se está usando. Lo anterior diferencia  la expresión let de la palabra reservada var , la cual define una variable global o local en una función sin importar el ámbito del bloque.

### let vs var

Cuando usamos let dentro de un bloque, podemos limitar el alcance de la variable a dicho bloque. Notemos la diferencia a con var, cuyo alcance reside dentro de la función donde ha sido declarada la variable.

```
var a = 5;
var b = 10;

if (a === 5) {
  let a = 4; // El alcance es dentro del bloque if
  var b = 1; // El alcance es global

  console.log(a);  // 4
  console.log(b);  // 1
} 

console.log(a); // 5
console.log(b); // 1
```

Fuente: [Developer Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/let)

Answer (score 4):

`let` define una variable local limitando su alcance al bloque de ejecución, expresión o declaración en la que se encuentre. Es una característica no estándar por lo que puede dar problemas en diferentes navegadores.

`var` define una variable limitando su ámbito a la función en la que se define o al ámbito global (si no se encuentra dentro de una función), independientemente del bloque de ejecución en el que se ejecute.

```js
{
  let variable_let = 'valor variable let';
  var variable_var = 'valor variable var';
  console.log('var dentro de bloque: ' + variable_var);
  console.log('let dentro de bloque: ' + variable_let);
}

console.log('var fuera de bloque: ' + variable_var);
console.log('let fuera de bloque: ' + variable_let);
```

Answer (score 2):

Varias, pero las más significativas tienen que ver con ámbito:

```
function cualquiera(){
  if (2 == 2){ // por poner algo
   var variable1 = 1
   let variable2 = 2
  }
  // aqui variable1 existe
  // aqui variable2 no existe
 console.log(variable1)
}
```

La idea (IMHO) es que uses `var` para cosas privadas del módulo y `let` para cosas que locales en funciones.