# mostrar y ocultar elementos html con javascript

Tags: javascript, html

estoy iniciándome en javascript y tengo un problema. Quiero hacer una web de FAQs y que al pinchar en una pregunta se desplieguen las respuestas. Pero al pinchar en la pregunta me aparece este error en el log del navegador *Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null* y no hace nada he mirado que exista la clase, que haya capturado el elemento, y no se que puedo mirar más. Adjunto código html y javascript actual. Gracias de antemano. Por cierto quiero hacerlo por delegación de eventos

```js
(function(){
 window.addEventListener('load', function(){
 
 var elementosH2 = faqs.getElementsByTagName("h2");
 var nodoH2;
 for(var i=0; i<elementosH2.length;i++){
  nodoH2 = elementosH2[i];
  nodoH2.addEventListener("click", cambiar);
 }
 
 function cambiar(e) {
   var h2 = e.target; // h2 es el nodoH2 actual
   if (h2.getAttribute("class") == "mas") {
    h2.setAttribute("class", "menos");
   }
   else {
    h2.setAttribute("class", "mas");
   }
   if (h2.nextElementSibling.getAttribute("class") == "cerrado") {
    h2.nextElementSibling.setAttribute("class", "abierto");
   }
   else {
    h2.nextElementSibling.setAttribute("class", "cerrado");
   }
  }
 });
}());
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title> Ejercicio FAQs</title>
 <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
    <section id="faqs">
        <h1>FAQs</h1>
   <h2 class="mas"><img src="mas.jpg"/> ¿Qué es jQuery?</h2>
   <div class="cerrado">
    <p>
     <img name="" src="menos.jpg"/>
     jQuery es una librería de funciones JavaScript que puedes utilizar para desarrollar sitios web.
    </p>
   </div>
   <h2 class="mas"><img src="mas.jpg"/>¿Por qué es tan popular jQuery?</h2>
   <div class="cerrado">
    <p>
     <img src="menos.jpg"/>Hay tres razones:
    </p>
    <ul>
     <li>Es gratuito</li>
     <li>Te permite hacer más cosas en menos tiempo</li>
     <li>Sus funciones son compatibles con todos los navegadores</li>
    </ul>
   </div>
    </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Tu función cambiar(e) requiere que le pases el parámetro e, como no se lo pasas al llamarla no reconoce el elemento que defines a partir de este parámetro y no puede encontrar atributos de algo no definido.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta @Carmen y como podría llamar a mi función pasandole los parámetros??

Comment: cambiar(nodoH2) por ejemplo dentro de tu bucle.

Comment: a mi me funciona tu código, cambia las clases `mas` y `cerrado` por `menos` y `abierto` y viceversa cuando pincho en un h2 y no obtengo errores

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Varias cosas a tener en cuenta:

1.- Como te decían en el comentario, no estás pasándole el elemento en la función. [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) espera una función como segundo parámetro. Puedes pasárselo como una función anónima:

```
nodoH2.addEventListener("click", function(){cambiar(this)});
```

2.- Uso de let y var: Acostúmbrate a usar `let` más a menudo. `var` crea variables globales lo que te puede dar problemas de conflicto entre variables o comportamientos no deseados. Más info [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/79809/cual-es-la-diferencia-de-usar-let-en-vez-de-var-en-javascript) y [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/let).

3.- Añadir el estilo de las imágenes vía CSS (no lo pongo porque no tengo las imágenes en la solución)

4.- Declarar la variable `faqs`: el motor de JS te la está creando con el valor del DOM "faqs" pero esto es una muy mala idea (más [info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/do-dom-tree-elements-with-ids-become-global-variables))

Faltarían cosas como, por ejemplo, cambiar la imagen de los `h2` al hacer click

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title> Ejercicio FAQs</title>  
  <style>
  .mas{display:inline;}
  .cerrado{display:none;}
  </style>
</head>

<body>
<section id="faqs">
    <h1>FAQs</h1>
  <h2 class="mas"><img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fatcow/32/add.png"/> ¿Qué es jQuery?</h2>
  <div class="cerrado">
   <p>     
    jQuery es una librería de funciones JavaScript que puedes utilizar para desarrollar sitios web.
   </p>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <h2 class="mas"><img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fatcow/32/add.png"/>¿Por qué es tan popular jQuery?</h2>
  <div class="cerrado">
   <p>
    Hay tres razones:
   </p>
   <ul>
    <li>Es gratuito</li>
    <li>Te permite hacer más cosas en menos tiempo</li>
    <li>Sus funciones son compatibles con todos los navegadores</li>
   </ul>
  </div>
</section>
<script>
(function(){
window.addEventListener('load', function(){

var elementosH2 = faqs.getElementsByTagName("h2");
var nodoH2;
for(var i=0; i<elementosH2.length;i++){
 nodoH2 = elementosH2[i];
 nodoH2.addEventListener("click", function(){cambiar(this)});
}

function cambiar(e) {
  var h2 = e; // h2 es el nodoH2 actual
  if (h2.getAttribute("class") == "mas") {
   h2.setAttribute("class", "menos");
  }
  else {
   h2.setAttribute("class", "mas");
  }
  if (h2.nextElementSibling.getAttribute("class") == "cerrado") {
   h2.nextElementSibling.setAttribute("class", "abierto");
  }
  else {
   h2.nextElementSibling.setAttribute("class", "cerrado");
  }
 }
});
}());
</script>
</body>

</html>
```