# Crear Array de Elementos insertados en una tabla Tabla HTML

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Quisiera saber quien pudiera ayudarme con este problema... Tengo una tabla en la que se insertan elementos mediante check's box, de los elementos insertados quiero crear un Array con Javascript pero mi problema es que en el array me introduce tambien los campos de el titulo de la tabla y un boton que esta en la parte inferior .... *Anexo codigo

```js
var tab=document.getElementById('ordenT');
var jsonArr=[];
for(var i=0; row<tab.rows[i]; i++)
{
  var col=row.cells;
  var jsonObj= { folio: col[0].innerHTML }
  jsonArr.push(jsonObj);
}
console.log(jsonArr);
```

```html
//CODIGO HTML 
<table class="form_table"  id="ordenT" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align: center; background-color:  #fff0b3 !important">
                  <b>Órdenes de Trabajo.</b>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr> 
    <td style="text-align: center">
      <input type="button" class="button" id="txtIdTramite" name="txtIdTramite" value="ASIGNAR ORDENES DE TRABAJO" autofocus="autofocus" onclick="enviar();">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4):

Varias cosas:

- La variable `row` del `for` no existe, tu variable de condición del bucle es `i`
- En dicho bucle la condición de parada tiene que ser `tab.rows.length`
- `row.cells` te da fallo porque `row` es `undefined`
- En cuanto al problema de que te obtiene todas las filas. Lo mejor es que, por un lado, saques el botón de tu tabla y por otro, para la cabecera pon el `tag <th>` en vez de `<td>` y en el bucle pon una condición con `indexOf()` para que no te obtenga aquellas filas con el `tag <th>`

Deberías tener algo de este estilo:

```js
let tab=document.getElementById('ordenT');
let jsonArr=[];              
for(let i=0; i<tab.rows.length; i++){ 
  if(tab.rows[i].innerHTML.indexOf("<th")<0){
    let col=tab.rows[i].cells;
    let jsonObj= { folio: col[0].innerHTML }
    jsonArr.push(jsonObj);
  }        
}
console.log(jsonArr);
```

```html
//CODIGO HTML 

 <table class="form_table"  id="ordenT" width="100%">
    <thead>
         <th style="text-align: center; background-color:  #fff0b3 !important">
                      <b>Órdenes de Trabajo.</b>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Dato 1
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Dato 2
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
 <input type="button" class="button" id="txtIdTramite" name="txtIdTramite" value="ASIGNAR ORDENES DE TRABAJO" autofocus="autofocus" onclick="enviar();"></input>
```

PD: Observarás que en vez de `var` estoy utilizando `let`. Si tu navegador no soporta `let` (Internet Explorer < 11) utiliza `var`. [Aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/79809/cual-es-la-diferencia-de-usar-let-en-vez-de-var-en-javascript) tienes más info.

**Edito (con el botón dentro de la tabla)**

```js
let tab=document.getElementById('ordenT');
    let jsonArr=[];              
    for(let i=0; i<tab.rows.length; i++){ 
      if(tab.rows[i].innerHTML.indexOf("<th")<0 && tab.rows[i].innerHTML.indexOf("button") < 0){
        let col=tab.rows[i].cells;
        let jsonObj= { folio: col[0].innerHTML }
        jsonArr.push(jsonObj);
      }        
    }
    console.log(jsonArr);
```

```html
<table class="form_table"  id="ordenT" width="100%">
        <thead>
             <th style="text-align: center; background-color:  #fff0b3 !important">
                          <b>Órdenes de Trabajo.</b>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Dato 1
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Dato 2
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="text-align: center">
                 <input type="button" class="button" id="txtIdTramite" name="txtIdTramite" value="ASIGNAR ORDENES DE TRABAJO" autofocus="autofocus" onclick="enviar();"></input>
          </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Hola, pero tengo una duda, si necesito que el botón este en la misma tabla no hay alguna opción de incluirlo sin que se agregue al array??

Comment: Sí, edito la respuesta.