# ¿Cómo almacenar INPUT por teclado tipo text en array?

Tags: javascript, array

Estoy intentado hacer el siguiente ejercicio:

- Haz una web con un input de tipo texto y dos botones “**Añadir**” y “**Mostrar**”
- Al pulsar el botón “Añadir”, se añadirá el contenido del input a un array vacío previamente creado (definir como variable global) y borrará el input ( `document.forms["nomForm"] ["nomInput"].value = ""` ).
- Al pulsar el botón “Mostrar”, se mostrará la lista de todos los elementos, uno por línea*

Pero no sé cómo debo hacer para que se guarde tipo ARRAY

De momento tengo:

```
<body>

    <form name="tercero" method="post">
        <label for="texto">Escribe un texto:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="texto" name="texto" maxlength="35"><br>

        <button type="button" onclick="añadir()">AÑADIR</button>

        <button type="button" onclick="mostrar()">MOSTRAR</button>

        <p id="demo"></p>
    </form>

    <script>

        function añadir(){
            var arraytexto = [];
            document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML=arraytexto;
            } 
        }

        function mostrar(){
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = arraytexto.join("*");
        }

    </script>


</body>
```

Comment: ¿Borrar el input o dejarlo vacío? por que son cosas distintas

Comment: Entiendo que una vez haga click en "Añadir" se añadirá al array y quedará vacío el input anterior, por si quiero volver a introducir un nuevo elemento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para declarar la variable global, debes ponerla fuera de cualquier función, y con el método `.push()` agregas valores al array.

Para limpiar el `input` debes poner su `value` vacio

```
 document.getElementById('texto').value = "";
```

```js
var arraytexto = [];

function añadir() {
  let palbras = document.getElementById('texto').value.split(" ");
  arraytexto = arraytexto.concat(palbras);
  document.getElementById('texto').value = ""; //limpias el array
}

function mostrar() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = arraytexto.join("<br>");
}
```

```html
<label for="texto">Escribe un texto:</label><br>
<input type="text" id="texto" name="texto" maxlength="35"><br>

<button type="button" onclick="añadir()">AÑADIR</button>

<button type="button" onclick="mostrar()">MOSTRAR</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Con esto he conseguido que se guardaran en el array e imprimirlos, pero necesito imprimirlos en formato lista, no separados con un guión, ni un asterisco (que era lo que tenía yo)...voy a ver si lo saco. Gran ayuda!! =)

Comment: Puedes remplazar el guion por `<br>` esto generara un espacio

Comment: arraytexto.join("<br>")

Comment: Claro, esto es si introduzco varios datos, dando cada vez click en "añadir", me los va sacando en forma lista cuando hago click en "mostrar". Pero, por ejemplo, si yo pongo "Hola soy Victoria", quiero que me salga: 
Hola
soy
Victoria

Comment: Revisalo de nuevo lo he editado.

Comment: Siii!!! Ahora sí, muchas gracias!! Eso era lo que buscaba!!

Comment: Te lo explico, la funcion `split(" ")` separa tu texto por espacios y lo convierte en un array, ahora debemos agregar todas las palabras separadas al array de palabras totales, y para ello usamos `.concat()`

Comment: He visto ambas funciones pero no sabía cómo utilizarlas en este caso. Gracias por la explicación. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Si no englobas dentro de un scope de función es decir dentro de `{}` por ejemplo a `var` o `let` ambas serían globales.

Por lo tanto puedes dejar a tu código de esta manera:

- Dos listeners, uno para cada botón
- Dentro del primer botón que agrega haces un push al vector
- Dentro del botón que muestra a los botones haces un `foreach` del vector recién llenado

**Propuesta**

```html
    <input id="numeros" type="text">
    <button id="agregar">Añadir</button>
    <button id="mostrar">Mostrar</button>
    <script>
        let numeros = []
        let numero = document.getElementById("numeros")
        let agregar = document.getElementById("agregar")
        let mostrar = document.getElementById("mostrar")
        
        agregar.addEventListener("click", () => {
          numeros.push(numero.value)
          numero.value = ""
          numero.focus()
          console.log(numeros)
        })
    
        mostrar.addEventListener("click", () => {
          numeros.forEach((numero) => {
            console.log(numero)
          })
        })
    </script>
```

Ahora si quieres que se imprima dentro del HTML, puedes hacerlo agregando cada número obtenido en las iteraciones con un salto de línea a una etiquet HTML

```html
    <input id="numeros" type="text">
    <button id="agregar">Añadir</button>
    <button id="mostrar">Mostrar</button>
    <div id="lista"></div>
    <script>
        let numeros = []
        let numero = document.getElementById("numeros")
        let agregar = document.getElementById("agregar")
        let mostrar = document.getElementById("mostrar")
        let lista   = document.getElementById("lista")
        
        agregar.addEventListener("click", () => {
          numeros.push(numero.value)
          numero.value = ""
          numero.focus()
        })
    
        mostrar.addEventListener("click", () => {
          numeros.forEach((numero) => {
            lista.innerText += numero+"\n"
          })
        })
    </script>
```

**Importante**

> Te recomiendo [leer esta pregunta y respuestas (que no son mias)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/56116/cuando-conviene-utilizar-var-let-y-const-en-ecma-script-6) pero te van a ayudar un montón con el tema del scope de las variables

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta pero lo he medio solucionado con la anterior, sois megarapidxs por aquí!! =)

Comment: Por cierto, gracias por la recomendación!!

Comment: Revisa el segundo código que agregue @Victoria_lunática :)

Comment: Muchas gracias.