# ¿En Javascript var, let y const son tipos de variables?

Tags: javascript, variables, tipos

En algunas ocasiones he escuchado hablar a algunos creadores de contenido (sobre programación en JAVASCRIPT) en youtube  que los tipos de variables que existen son var, let y const.

Cuando hablamos de **var**, **let** y **const** nos referimos a palabras reservadas que permiten declarar una variable o una constante:

```
/*var (Pertenece a la forma antigua de declarar una variable en javascript y actualmente let 
la reemplaza).*/

//let (Pertenece a las nuevas mejoras de javascript y es usada para declarar una variable).

//const (Es usada para declarar una constante).
```

Por otro lado, los valores booleanos, numéricos, cadenas de texto, etc. hacen referencia al tipo de dato que contiene la variable.

```
let numero = 12; //Variable con un dato de tipo number o cadena o número.
let texto = "Hola mundo";//Variable con un dato de tipo string o cadena de texto.
let booleano = true;//Variable con un dato de tipo boolean o booleana.
```

¿Entonces, al referirnos a  **var**, **let** y **const** como tipos de variables no estamos haciendo un buen uso de la terminología de javascript?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cuando conviene utilizar var, let y const en ECMA Script 6?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/56116/cuando-conviene-utilizar-var-let-y-const-en-ecma-script-6)

Comment: Exacto. Son formas de declarar una variable. no tipos de variables. Lo que no tengo claro es cual es la pregunta ;)

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. El formato de tu pregunta no es adecuado. Si bien la pregunta del título puede ser correcta, el contenido de la pregunta parece más la argumentación de una respuesta a la misma pregunta. Si es lo que pretendes, puedes usar el espacio de respuestas para responder tu propia pregunta. Además, considera hacer una búsqueda en el sitio por preguntas relacionadas o iguales antes de publicar la tuya, esto con la idea de no duplicar contenido. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Efectivamente es un mal uso del lenguaje, deberíamos hablar de tipos de **declaración** de variables:

- `const` define constantes. Tiene alcance de bloque, como let.
- `var` define variables con un alcance de función.
- `let` define variables con un alcance de bloque y a partir de la línea en la que se declaran.

Comment: ¡Gracias por su aporte Pablo Lozano! Muy buena su aclaración.

Answer (score 0):

Lo estas enfocando mal. let, var y const solo sirve para declarar variables y no para indicar el tipado de la variable, de hecho Javascript no tiene tipado. si quieres tipar javascript deberás usar Typescript.

En el caso que no sepas como o cuando utilizar las declaraciones var, let o const aquí tienes la pregunta donde explican claramente como y cuando usarlo: [link](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/56116/cuando-conviene-utilizar-var-let-y-const-en-ecma-script-6)

Comment: ¡@Jordi Baliellas gracias por tu colaboración, estoy diciendo que var, let y const no hacen referencia al tipo de variables, sino que hacen referencia al tipo de declaración como lo indica @Pablo Lozano!