# ¿Cuàl es la diferencia entre string y var en java script?

Tags: javascript, string

En otras fuentes encontre que dan el mismo resultado , pero en otros decia que cambia en algunos aspectos.

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y muestra a qué fuentes te estás refiriendo (en caso de hacerlo, no olvides detallar el contenido de los enlaces). Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Además, `var` es para declarar una variable, y `String` es un tipo de objeto. ¿A qué estás intentando hacer referencia?

Comment: Son conceptos bastante distintos. String es un tipo de dato. Por otro lado, var se utilizaba (está obsoleto) para declarar variables, actualmente se utilizan let o const según el caso. El contenido de éstas puede variar en cuanto al tipo de dato. Los tipos de datos que podés usar en js podrías buscarlos en este link:
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures Demás está decir que es clave leer siempre la documentación de la tecnología que utilizamos. Espero haber sido de ayuda, saludos!

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿En Javascript var, let y const son tipos de variables?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/400634/en-javascript-var-let-y-const-son-tipos-de-variables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No entiendo del a que te refieres pero:

"var" se usa para declarar variables.

ejemplo rápido de uso de var:

```js
var a = 10;

console.log(a);
```

String es un tipo de dato, a menos que te refieras a la clase String que es un poco diferente.

Ejemplo:

```js
//Variable de tipo de dato String

var a = "Hola Mundo";

let b = "Hola Mundo";

console.log(a);

console.log(b);

//Uso de String como clase

String.prototype.pTexto = String.prototype.pTexto || function() {
    return this.toLowerCase();
};

// Uso del nuevo método
a = a.pTexto();

b = b.pTexto();

console.log(a);

console.log(b);
```